# how to set label for bar stack to echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am using echarts.
this is my chart:

[image: echarts]

I have several xaxix this picture shows one xaxis data and two bar(stack).
info:stack put data on top of each other in one xaxis data.
so in this case I have Two bar

my question is: how can I set label for each stack(not xaxis label I am showing with red) there is an option for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the way to show label in echarts

```
 series : [
        {
            name:'Name',
            type:'bar',
            stack: 'StackName',
            itemStyle : { normal: {label : {show: true, position: 'inside*'}}},
            data:[sample data]
        }
```

If you show your code it would be more helpful to figuring out.

Comment: no it shows label inside items I wand to set label for each bar in same stack I have showed with red in picture

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to to it.

`xAxis : [
        {
            type : 'category',
            data : ["Name 1","Name 2"]
        }
    ],`